# Grouping in T-SQL and choosing the longest name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

I am using SQL Server 2012. I was trying to resolve a "typical" grouping problem. But I couldn't resolve this correctly.

Imagine that you have this table:

[image]

I would like to group by position. It could be easy:

```
select position, COUNT(*)
from testsql
group by position
```

But, I would like to group by position, and take the longest name (myname) of every position.

```
select 
    myid, myname, position, len(myname) as lenname
from 
    testsql
group by 
    myid, myname, position
having
    myname = select (max(len(myname))) from testsql /*Obviously it doesn't work */
order by
    position asc;
```

Comment: It's a **position** - not a "possition" (one `s` is **quite** enough!)

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way of doing this using ROW_NUMBER. It only hits the base table one time.

```
select myid
    , myname
    , possition
from
(
    select myid
        , myname
        , possition
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by possition order by LEN(myname) desc)
    from testsql
) x
where x.RowNum = 1
```

Comment: If the implication is that the other answer will hit the table multiple times this may well not be the case. http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/07/28/the-segment-top-query-optimisation.aspx

Comment: @SeanLange Totally correct. Your way is more efficient. Thanks for comment.

Answer (score 1):

I had thought to use a subquery with an alias. 
And finally, it would be the best option; because, after that, I make a join to link the MAX(LEN(myname) of the subquery with the myname of the normal table.

This is the solution. I am sure that maybe it is not the best.

```
select myid, myname, testsql.possition, LEN(myname) AS lenname
from testsql
    INNER JOIN (
        select possition, max(LEN(myname)) AS lenname2
        FROM testsql
        group by possition) as testsql2
            ON testsql.possition = testsql2.possition
where LEN(testsql.myname) = lenname2
GROUP BY myid, myname
ORDER BY possition ASC;
```

[image]

Please, don't doubt to post more comments if you want.

Thanks!